# Python Help -- How to extract a specific range of values from a 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays

In python, is there a command that allow me to extract a specific subset of a given array?

For example, let's say that I have the following 1D array:

```
x = np.array([1,0,35,9,1,23,10,2,4,8,3])
```

How do I get only element between 2 and 10? So, I want the output to be something like:

```
subx = [9,2,4,8,3]
```

Just to clarify, I do not want the indices. I just want the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the methods is to use a `list comprehension`
Note: Inclusive of 2, the lower bound but excluding 10, the upper bound

```
x = [1,0,35,9,1,23,10,2,4,8,3]
y = [c for c in x if c >=2 and c<10]
```

Since you are using `numpy`

Method 1:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.where(np.logical_and(x>=2, x<10))
```

Method 2:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,0,35,9,1,23,10,2,4,8,3])
y = x[(x>=2) * (x<10)]
```

Comment: Just to note, your version of numpy does not yield the desired output. You can correct it by indexing `[0]` at the end.

Comment: Your second option doesn't seem to work. Is there a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo. I am using `numpy-1.18.2` on a Linux machine. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I made a mistake. After fixing it, your methods do seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
a=[1,0,35,9,1,23,10,2,4,8,3]
li=[]
for ele in a:
    if ele in range(2,10):
        li.append(ele)
print(li)
```

Output:

```
[9, 2, 4, 8, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a numpy array, you can do:

```
x[(x >= 2) & (x < 10)]
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error:TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: @HelixFossil, then you're having a list as opposed to what you have shown in the question.

Comment: You are right. I was being sloppy when I test your solution. By actually using np.array, this solution works!